# выбрать последние свойства сложного объекта

Tags: javascript, lodash

возможный объект:

```js
{
  "a": {
    "b": {
      "c": true
    },
    "d": {
      "e": false,
      "e2": {
        "e22": true
      }
    },
    "f": {
      "g": {
        "h": [1, 'abc', 3, 'xyz', 5, 0]
      }
    }
  },
  "i": {
    "j": {
      "k": {
        "l": {
          "m": false
        }
      },
      "n": {
        "p": {
          "q": {
            "r": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

а)вложенность не известна.

б)можно ли на ходу фильтровать true|false|Array

... значения только логические или одномерный массив

---

1)как взять все последние свойства "каждой ветки" в виде массива объектов, то есть в данном случае:

```js
[{c: true}, {e: false}, {e22: true}, {h: [1, 'abc', 3, 'xyz', 5, 0]}, {m: false}, {r: true}]
```

2) возможно ли при этом выбрать только ключи (без предыдущей выборки):

```js
[c, e, e22, h, m, r]
```

! Lodash приветствуется (в приоритете) !

Comment: Обычный алгоритм типа dfs.

Comment: В js свойства в объекте не сортированы и понятие «последний» к ним не применимо

Comment: @AlexeyTen, тут "последний" - значит самый глубокий :-)

Answer (score 1):

Вот, примерно так?

```js
let o = obj();

let isObj = o => typeof o === "object" && !Array.isArray(o);
let map = (func, o, k) => Object.keys(o).flatMap(k => func(o[k], k));
let deepObj = (o, k) => isObj(o) ? map(deepObj, o, k) : {[k]:o};
let deepKey = (o, k) => isObj(o) ? map(deepKey, o, k) : k;

console.log(JSON.stringify(deepObj(o)))
console.log(JSON.stringify(deepKey(o)))

function obj(){
  return {
  "a": {
    "b": {
      "c": true
    },
    "d": {
      "e": false,
      "e2": {
        "e22": true
      }
    },
    "f": {
      "g": {
        "h": [1, 'abc', 3, 'xyz', 5, 0]
      }
    }
  },
  "i": {
    "j": {
      "k": {
        "l": {
          "m": false
        }
      },
      "n": {
        "p": {
          "q": {
            "r": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вместо рекурсии, также возможно обходить свойства объектов с использованием цикла.

Для этого можно хранить список пар ключ-значение для проверки.

В цикле бежать по элементам данного списка.

На каждой итерации цикла нужно брать из списка пару ключ-значение и если значение является объектом, но не является массивом, добавлять в список все его ключи и значения, в противном случае складывать в результирующий список ключ, либо то, что требуется.

Цикл должен работать до тех пор, пока в списке есть хотя бы один элемент.

Пример реализации:

```js
let o = obj();

function deepest (o){
  var props = Object.entries(o);
  var result = [];
  while(props.length){
    var [key, val] = props.pop();
    if(typeof val == 'object' && !Array.isArray(val)){
      props.unshift(...Object.entries(val).reverse());
      continue;
    }
    
    result.push(key);
  }
  return result;
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(deepest(o)))

function obj(){
  return {
    "a": {
      "b": {
        "c": true
      },
      "d": {
        "e": false,
        "e2": {
          "e22": true
        }
      },
      "f": {
        "g": {
          "h": [1, 2, 3]
        }
      }
    },
    "i": {
      "j": {
        "k": {
          "l": {
            "m": false
          }
        },
        "n": {
          "p": {
            "q": {
              "r": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример, для только ключей, или значений измените пуш в массив.

```js
const a = {
    "a": {
      "b": {
        "c": true
      },
      "d": {
        "e": false,
        "e2": {
          "e22": true
        }
      },
      "f": {
        "g": {
          "h": [1, 'abc', 3, 'xyz', 5, 0]
        }
      }
    },
    "i": {
      "j": {
        "k": {
          "l": {
            "m": false
          }
        },
        "n": {
          "p": {
            "q": {
              "r": true
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }


function getDeep(object, newArr = []){

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(object)){
        if (!Array.isArray(value) && typeof value === 'object') {
          getDeep(value, newArr);
          continue;
        }
        newArr.push({[key]:value});
    }
    return newArr
} 

console.log(getDeep(a))
```